# Retrofit - Combining Integer arraylist with Image file

Tags: android, retrofit2

Requirement is to upload image along with plain text and plain data has **Arraylist of integers**.
I am using @PartMap for plain data

For image part here is my code

```
imageFile = new File(imagePath);
imageBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile);
multipartImageBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file_name", imageFile.getName(), imageBody);
```

For plain data

```
userIdBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), userId);
customerTypeBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), typeOfCustomer);
```

Combining plain data

```
HashMap<String, RequestBody> partMap = new HashMap<>();
partMap.put("userId", userIdBody);
partMap.put("customer_type", customerTypeBody);
```

The request

```
@POST<T> methodName(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params, @Part MultipartBody.Part imageParam);
```

Issue occurs if i try to add integer listarray as Requestbody, the data is converted to string which server fails to parse rather we should be sending correct data from app side itself

What i tried

```
RequestBody.create(Mediatype,byte[])
```

Requestbody has this method which accepts our data as byte array,i converted arraylist to byte array but result was not as expected.

Is there any other possibility that i should try?

Comment: You can use multipart to upload image with text data

Comment: I have more than one text data actually

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this is the interface part

```
@Multipart
@POST("your/link")
Call<SuccessMessage> yourMethod(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part[] data);//here you can use partmap also
```

and here is how it is used

```
  MultipartBody.Part img = RequestHelper.multiPartBobyPart(image, "image");


    MultipartBody.Part[] parts = new MultipartBody.Part[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            parts[i] = RequestHelper.multiPartBobyPart(yourStringArrayList.get(i), "var[]");
        }
    Call<SuccessMessage> call = mNetworkInterface.applyForDomesticJob(img, parts);
    call.enqueue(this);
```

And here is the request helper class

```
public final class RequestHelper {

public static MultipartBody.Part multiPartBobyPart(java.io.File file, String parameterName) {
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(parameterName, file == null ? "noFile" : file.getName(),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file == null ? new java.io.File("") : file));
}

public static RequestBody getRequestBody(String parameter) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), parameter);
}


public static MultipartBody.Part multiPartBobyPart(String data, String parameterName) {
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(parameterName, data);
}
```

}

use [this link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) for more detailed information

Comment: It works for plain String data but not with int arraylist.

Comment: Do you want to send an array of ints?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from `int[]` to `byte[]` sounds like endianess issue. You should check in which endianess the server accepts the data and see if your conversion code is using the same endianess. You can use ByteBuffer to do the conversion, it has the `order()` method to specify endianess.

I haven't had any issues with **retrofit's** RequestBody.create myself, so I suspect this is the issue here.